# How to send line of text from server to client in C?

Tags: c, server, client

This program, on the server side, asks the user for an array size, array elements and an integer value to be searched in the array. If found it prints a message such as "The value 87 occurs at index position 4" and sends it back to client. I have managed to come up with the following code for server and client. However, how do I send the result of the search such as "The value 87 occurs at index position 4" back to server from client?

Client Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10   //maximum array size

int main (void)
{
    int fda;      // to write to server
    int fdb;      // to read response from server

    struct{
        int size;
        int i;
        int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    } input;

    if((fda=open("FIFO_to_server", O_WRONLY))<0)
        printf("cant open fifo to write");

    printf("Client: Please enter size of the array:  ");
    scanf("%d", &input.size);

    printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
    scanf(%d", &arr[i]);
  } 

  write(fda, &input, sizeof(input));
  close(fda);

  printf("\nClient: Got the array sent, now waiting for response ");

  if((fdb=open("FIFO_to_client", O_RDONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to read");

  close(fdb);

  printf ("\nall done!\n");

}
```

Server Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (void)
{
    int fda;      // to read from client
    int fdb;      // to write
    int i;
    int toSearch;
    int found;
    int finish;

    /* Create the fifos and open them  */
    if ((mkfifo("FIFO_to_server",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
        perror("cant create FIFO_to_server");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if ((mkfifo("FIFO_to_client",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
        perror("cant create FIFO_to_client");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if((fda=open("FIFO_to_server", O_RDONLY))<0)
        printf("cant open fifo to write");

    if((fdb=open("FIFO_to_client", O_WRONLY))<0)
        printf("cant open file to read");

    finish=read(fda, &input, sizeof(input));

    printf("Server: just got the array: %d", arr);
    printf("\Enter the integer to be searched in the array: ");

    found = 0;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == toSearch)
        {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found == 1)
    {
        printf("\n%d is found at position %d", toSearch, i + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d is not found in the array", toSearch);
    }
    return 0;


close(fdb);
unlink("FIFO_to_client");

close(fda);
unlink("FIFO_to_server");
}
```

Comment: Use `sprintf()` to put the message into a string, then use `write()` to write it to `fdb`.

Comment: You need to open both FIFOs in the client before reading because the server won't send anything until the client opens the second FIFO and the client won't open the second FIFO until it receives something from the server.  The processes are deadlocked.

Comment: Or open them in `O_NBLOCK` mode.

Comment: The server has code outside the `main()` function. The `close` and `unlink` calls need to be before `return 0;`

Comment: The client code doesn't compile; there is no variable `arr`, though the `input` structure has a member `arr`.

Comment: @Barmar What would be the syntax for the sprintf?

Comment: The same as the syntax for your `printf`, it just writes to a string variable.

Comment: `sprintf(string, "%d is found at position %d", toSearch, i + 1);`